# Is there any suffix expressing “demand a lot”?

Tags: suffixes, phrasing

For example, *a job that demands a lot of effort is effort-****? Or *a program costs lots of money is money-****? Or *a task needs high patience is patience-****?

Comment: As a joke, we'll sometimes add the suffix `-vore` to something that demands a lot.  E.g., the job is a _chronovore_, it eats up all your time.

Comment: @JCooper: I think this helps! May be I can use it in a situation supposed to be humorous. Thanks.

Comment: @trVoldemort: use it sparingly.  `-vore` tacked onto the wrong words -- ones that don't seem Greek-rooted -- can just look stupid.  I wouldn't use "moneyvore", for instance, because it just looks and sounds wrong.

Comment: I like it, @JCooper. Maybe I can start a Twitter trend out of this :P

Comment: @Rhodri It's true that some things sound better than others.  You can also add `-ivorous` to better effect in some cases.  "Moneyvorous" would be reasonable, if a little silly---but it's _supposed_ to be funny.  If you're going all-out "pecunivorous" would probably be more correct for that case.

Comment: ...Well, for anything that demands lots of effort, money, and/or patience, I would want to use "odious."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*-Intensive* would be one of those. The pertinent definition, according to the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1258496#m_en_us1258496) is

> concentrating on or making much use of a specified thing

Thus, *labor-intensive*, *cost-intensive*, etc. I'm not sure this would work for *patience*, though!

Answer (score 6):

You might try "-intensive", at least with regards to effort.

Answer (score 5):

Some nouns can take the suffix -some to indicate propensity or demand.  Examples include:

- Bothersome
- Worrisome
- Winsome
- Troublesome
- Fearsome
- Loathsome
- Lonesome

Other suffixes with a similar meaning are -ful, -ive, and -ly.  These tend to describe a property of an object more than describing a demand for something.  In the three examples given in the question, none take on any of these suffixes.  However, you could replace money--- with *costly*, effort--- with *intensive*, and patience--- with *peaceful*.  These aren't exactly the same, but they're pretty close.

Answer (score 5):

You could say:

> effort intensive
>
> money hungry
>
> time consuming
>
> resource draining

Answer (score 3):

Something that absorbs a lot of a given commodity is often referred to as a sink.

For example

A project which absorbs a lot of my time could be referred to as a [time sink](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time_sink).

World of Warcraft has been referred to as a [life-sink](http://games.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=1898980&cid=34472774).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single suffix that would fit the examples.

- A job that demands a lot of effort is 'hard' or 'demanding' or 'exhausting' or ...
- A program that costs a lot of money is 'expensive'.
- A task that requires a lot of patience is 'exasperating' or 'demanding' or ...

Comment: Sorry, but what I meant is not a word, but a suffix, added after the noun.

Comment: @trVoldemort: I know - and I said I do not think there is a single suffix that fits the bill, though I'll concede that 'intensive' is likely as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'sapping'

money-sapping hobby

time-sapping

Sapping is the action of extracting sap from a tree, so these things sap your energy, time, money, etc.